# What does TabActivity & getDrawable() is deprecated mean? And can it cause your application to close?

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is the image that show the objects that are depreciated...?
What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: Have you at all considered googling that question?

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means that you should not use it anymore but a new implementation of it, because it will be removed from framework / language whatever in future releases. In most cases there is a description at this method or documentation what you have to use instead.